# Dart compareTo() sometimes returns different result than javascript localeCompare()

Tags: javascript, dart

I'm looking for a javascript function that compares two strings in a "standard" way, or at least in the same way it does in **dart**.

I have this code in **dart** that give two strings it checks which is the largest and creates a single string separated by a "-" with the largest string in front.

```
//dart code
void main() {
  String currentUserId = "bbijdF7zKgR7jOIAs7Ka86jwdRu1";
  String peerId = "UVvUo4xCM4N4TtiFWL5B6vOFzN53";
  String groupChatId = "";
  if (currentUserId.compareTo(peerId) > 0) {
    groupChatId = '$currentUserId-$peerId';
  } else {
    groupChatId = '$peerId-$currentUserId';
  }
  print(groupChatId);
}
```

The print will return `bbijdF7zKgR7jOIAs7Ka86jwdRu1-UVvUo4xCM4N4TtiFWL5B6vOFzN53`

So far no problem.

Now I should replicate this code in javascript and I found the `localeCompare` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function which should do the same thing as `compareTo()` [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/compareTo.html) in dart. But this is not the case since, in the case of the two strings, they have different results.

```
//js code
var currentUserId = "bbijdF7zKgR7jOIAs7Ka86jwdRu1";
var peerId = "UVvUo4xCM4N4TtiFWL5B6vOFzN53";
var groupChatId = "";
if (currentUserId.localeCompare(peerId) > 0) {
  groupChatId = `${currentUserId}-${peerId}`
} else {
  groupChatId = `${peerId}-${currentUserId}`
}
console.log(groupChatId)
```

The print will return `UVvUo4xCM4N4TtiFWL5B6vOFzN53-bbijdF7zKgR7jOIAs7Ka86jwdRu1`

There are rare cases in which they give two different results, but this is precisely the problem. Is there any function in javascript that behaves like the `compareTo` in dart?

If anyone could explain to me why these two functions sometimes differ in the result I would be very grateful

Comment: You have mistake in JS code. You don't have `peerId.id`, replace it with `peerId`

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, `compareTo` sorts the string by the character's code point but when using `localeCompare` the strings are compared in lexicographic order based on the user's current language. Additionally, the result from `localeCompare` [may not be consistent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#using_locales) between users with different locale settings.

A better way to compare your strings would be to add them to an array and [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them. This also orders by code point and will be consistent regardless of the user's locale setting. However, since you want the lower value string first you will need a custom sorting function to handle this.

Then, instead of using string literals to combine, just `.join()` the array with the `-` character.

```js
let userId = "bbijdF7zKgR7jOIAs7Ka86jwdRu1";
let peerId = "UVvUo4xCM4N4TtiFWL5B6vOFzN53";

let chatId = [userId, peerId].sort(
  new Intl.Collator('en', { caseFirst: 'lower' }).compare
).join('-');

console.log(chatId);
```

This has proven to be surprisingly difficult. Hopefully this solution behaves as you expect in all circumstances.

Comment: `x.localeCompare(y) == false` is semantically nonsensical. `localeCompare` returns a negative number, 0, or a positive number.

Comment: That's right, and `-1 == false`. It was simply an example to demonstrate the truthyness, not code that is intended to be executed.

Comment: You got the same result in JS like OP result so the another way to comparing is not make any sense and you didn't explain why the answers in dart and in JS are different

Comment: @Besworks But using `false` and `true` is a confusing demonstration.  I don't see the point in relying on JavaScript's (sometimes unintuitive) notion of truthiness.

Comment: @EzioMercer The `sort` approach is better, but the OP wanted the items in *reversed* sort order.  The code here neglected to apply that reversal, which is why the result is the same.

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't think that OP just want to get the reversed answer in JS because to get this the OP can just invert his condition. And I understand that `sort` is better but it requeried to creat an array, sort, reverse and join. So OP can just use compare operator (`<`, `>`, ...) operator instead of `localCompare`. And I think that OP want to know the main difference between comparing strongs in dart and in JS

Comment: @EzioMercer The OP wants to reproduce the order from the Dart code.  The Dart `compareTo` method will compare characters by the values of the UTF-16 code units, and the OP's Dart code places the "larger" value first in the resulting string.  The OP can't just invert the condition to `localeCompare` because `localeCompare` depends on the language (and does other things, such as doing natural number sorting).

Comment: @jamesdlin You are completely right :) It was my fault when I said "OP can just invert". I didn't mean that this is right solution in any case. But instead of `sort` OP can just use compare operator which doesn't require any arrays or additional methods. And I think that your explanation about how do `compareTo` and `localCompare` work that what OP need to know

Comment: So I understand that `localeCompare` and `compareTo` essentially have a different way of ordering in some specific cases.
Thanks @Besworks I will test your solution.
As for using the comparison operators, I had not considered this option but I will try since the sorting represented by `comapreTo` is a total ordering of num values, with special cases for floats.